# How can I send XMPP messages after a successful transaction?

Tags: java, design-patterns, ejb-3.0, stateless

In my project I have all services designed as stateless session beans. During the workflow, new data is created and this should be reported back to the clients. I only want to send this messages when the transaction is successfully committed.

I have a ServletContextListener registered which dispatches my xmpp packets (smack library). When I receive a packet, I locate my dispatching stateful session bean and start the processing of the request.

```
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
    try{
        if(packet instanceof RawRequest){
            DispatchIQService service = Core.lookup(DispatchIQService.class);
            service.process(connection, (RawRequest)packet);
            // sending of the messages should happen here, because transaction completed successful.
        }else{
            log.debug("Packet ignored: " + packet.toXML());
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e, e);
    }
}
```

1. How can I collect this generated messages during the workflow accross multiple beans? I would return this list from the dispatch bean and send the messages afterwards. My simple solution would be to route through a list where I add my messages, but is there a more elegant way?
2. I have an XMPP resource (roster http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html) which I have to access from all beans. How can I accomplish that? Store it into a static variable and synchronize the access to it doesn't sound very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markus, I'm not a guru of J2EE, but for your purposes I recommend taking a look at [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service). This will help you implement message-based approach.
As for me, I used to go with RabbitMQ system. It was great experience, but additional software is required to run the system.

Comment: The "problem" is that in case of an error & rollback i do not want to send this generated messages and must remove it from the queue. Can i accomplish that with jms? I have no experience with it.

Comment: Sorry, I might get you wrong... Do you mean that you don't want message to be delivered in case of error or rollback?

Comment: Correct. :) The messages should only be send when the transaction commits successfull. After the service.process() method would be sufficient. So my straight-forward solution would be to pass a list through the workflow and add messages to it. Then the dispatch service returns it and i send the messages.

Comment: What prevents you from sending JMS message strictly in case of successful service.process()?

Comment: When the queue is exclusively for my thread then it would work fine i think. Is that possible?

Comment: If you send messages from a single thread then you have no problems. If you want to send messages from multiple threads, you will have to synchronize access to some object (in case of RabbitMQ such object is Channel). But there is not so much to do too (if I remember, even simple synchronized block works fine). Note that actual queue doesn't belong to JVM but to messaging service implementation, that's why you have to synchronize Java-object yourself